# Looking for a way to extract specific nested items in xml using RegEx

Tags: c#, regex, xml-parsing

I am in need of help from some mad regex wizard. Or maybe someone who is not as noobish as me. It would really be appreciated...

I have an xml string with a list of countries that has some nesting that I cannot seem to deal with.

In every country there is:

1. A list of names for said country in different languages;
2. A list of cities which all also have:

   - A list of names for said city in different languages;
3. A list of states which all also have:

   1. A list of names for said statein different languages;
   2. A list of cities which all also have:

      - a list of names for said city in different languages;

I'm trying to parse that xml and turn the data into objects that I can use in my code and I've somehow managed to figure out an idea of how to do that but I cannot find a way to separate the country names from the ones for the states/cities. Does anybody have an idea how to match only the names that are meant for the country?

How the xml looks like:

```
     <xsd:country xsd1:id="..." xsd1:name="..." xsd:isoCode="..." xmlns:xsd1="...">
        <xsd:state xsd1:id="..." xsd1:name="..." xsd:isoCode="...">
           <xsd:city xsd1:id="..." xsd1:name="..." xsd:isoCode="...">
              <xsd:name xsd1:lang="..." xsd1:name="..."/>
              <xsd:name xsd1:lang="..." xsd1:name="..."/>
              ...
           </xsd:city>
           <xsd:city xsd1:id="..." xsd1:name="..." xsd:isoCode="...">
              ...
           </xsd:city>
           <xsd:name xsd1:lang="..." xsd1:name="..."/>
           <xsd:name xsd1:lang="..." xsd1:name="..."/>
           ...
        </xsd:state>
        <xsd:state xsd1:id="..." xsd1:name="..." xsd:isoCode="...">
           ...
        </xsd:state>

        <xsd:city xsd1:id="..." xsd1:name="..." xsd:isoCode="...">
           <xsd:name xsd1:lang="..." xsd1:name="..."/>
           <xsd:name xsd1:lang="..." xsd1:name="..."/>
           ...
        </xsd:city>
        <xsd:city xsd1:id="..." xsd1:name="..." xsd:isoCode="...">
           ...
        </xsd:city>

        <xsd:name xsd1:lang="..." xsd1:name="..."/>
        <xsd:name xsd1:lang="..." xsd1:name="..."/>
        ...
     </xsd:country>
```

The simplest regex I've come to is the following:

```html
(?<countryNames><xsd:name.*?xsd1:lang="(?<lantuage>.*?)?".*?xsd1:name="(?<name>.*?)?".*?\/>)
```

...that however catches all names.

PS. I'm using C# to process the xml string although I don't think that matters much.

See demo with xml [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/XenfN3/1)

Comment: If you reconsider your approach there are also a lot of questions on parsing XML with proper XDocument/XmlDocument APIs... Otherwise Standard "parse XHTML with RegEx" covers all.

Comment: The country names are enclosed in the country open/close tags. Delete the city and state tag and contents and left wit country and there nam

Comment: Country name is in the name attribute of country open tag.  <xsd:country xsd1:id="..." `xsd1:name="..."` xsd:isoCode="..." xmlns:xsd1="...">